# Interpreting significant OR after non-significant effect of covariate

Tags: regression, logistic, statistical-significance, interpretation

I've done logistic regression in SAS and as one of independant variables I had ordinal variable with 4 levels. The type 3 Wald test was not significant for this variable, but odds ratios were sigificant at 0.05 significance level. Can these be interpreted as significant or after the non significance of the whole variable it should not be interpreted at all?

[image]

Thanks for advice, Matyas